# Open a GIF image, increase the 'canvas' by 100 pixels

Tags: php, resize, gd, gif

Hay, I want to use PHP's GD library to open a GIF image and increase the canvas's height by 100 pixels, then fill the new space with the hex colour #EEEEEE.

Does anyone have any idea how i would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is "Does anyone have any idea how i would do this?" Then the answer is yes. Most probably someone have an idea how you could do it. :)

Otherwise this should do the trick:

```
$image = imagecreatefromgif('file.gif');
list($imageWidth, $imageHeight) = getimagesize('file.gif');
$newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight+100);
$gray=imagecolorallocate($newimage, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE);
imagefill($newimage,0,0,$gray);
imagecopy($newimage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imageWidth, $imageHeight);
imagegif($newimage,'newimage.gif');
```

Comment: This works, however the function 'getimagesize' doesn't work with a GD image, it has to be a path to a file. Thanks for this.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. Seems to stretch the image. Any ideas?

Comment: ..this does work, but contains another bug. The $imageHeight+100 in imagecopyresampled() should be just $imageHeight

Comment: oops sorry for that, i was typing code straight to the answer field without actually testing it.  Thanks for spotting this bugs.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the original size with [`getimagesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)
2. Use [`imagecreate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) to create your "new" image with the desired size
3. Fill the new image with `#eeeeee` using [`imagecolorallocate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php) (see note)
4. Use [`imagecopy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) to copy your original image into the new one